# Windows Scheduler Wont run program

Tags: windows-10

I have set up windows scheduler to run a python script at the same time every day.

It only runs when I have windows scheduler open even though I have taken off "Only run when computer is on AC" and turned on "Run whether user is logged on or not" along with "Wake computer to run this task"

Is it because I have a password to login to my computer?

I can't get anything to work.

---

[image]

---

[image]

---

[image]

---

[image]

Comment: Go to Task Scheduler Security Option and set to run with Highest Privileges.  That will have you enter credentials along with Password. See if that helps.

Comment: It didn't ask for my credentials, but i will give that a try.
Could it be because i have it set to "Configure for: Windows Vista Windows Server 2008" and my computer runs windows 10?

I figured that was not the issue because all of these run when I run them on demand.

Comment: @Gio_Bart - No, that isn’t a reasonable explanation for the reason the task isn’t running

Comment: That may be because you are likely the administrator of your computer. But do set for Highest Privileges and try that.

Comment: Doesn't the task run at all, or does it run and fail? (Add to your comment `@harrymc` for me to be notified.)

Comment: it does not run at all @harrymc

As i'm trying things, i noticed something else, it will run when I run it on demand, but will not run at it's scheduled time even if i'm on my computer. 

I have "wake computer to run task" checked, could that be a reason it won't run when I'm actually on my computer.

Comment: No, it only means that the Scheduler will wake the computer from sleep, if necessary. You would need to add screenshots of all the Task Scheduler screens for us, because this is a weird behavior.

Comment: thanks @harrymc i added a picture

Comment: Perhaps try repairing Task Scheduler with DISM / SFC:  ......  (1) Open cmd.exe with Run as Administrator.
(2) DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-image /StartComponentCleanup
(3) DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-Image /Restorehealth
(4) SFC /SCANNOW
(5) Restart when all the above is complete and test.

Comment: We need screenshots of all the screens.

Comment: @harrymc added.

Comment: The settings seem to be entirely normal. The only one that might cause a very farfetched problem is "Stop the task if it runs longer than: 3 days", so check that it isn't still running. Try also a cold reboot after shutdown. If nothing is found, test Windows integrity by running the commands [Dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/7808-use-dism-repair-windows-10-image.html) and then [sfc /scannow](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/2895-run-sfc-command-windows-10-a.html).

Comment: @harrymc any opions on a 3rd party app? At this point i feel like i've tried 15 configurations. I'm tired of trying to find the needle in the haystack. Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: Did you consider the possibility that the problem is with your python script?

Comment: @harrymc i have not because when i run the task scheduler manually everything works as expected. The only thing that will not work is it won't run when my computer is closed.

Comment: Do you mean that the problem is just that the Task Scheduler doesn't manage to wake up the computer?